# How to subset multiple pandas data frames from a single time series data frame using row level iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a pandas data frame with 2 columns (time series date and value)

Input data frame:

| date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | -2 |
| 2021-05-02 | 3 |
| 2021-05-03 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 4 |
| 2021-05-05 | 6 |
| 2021-05-06 | -3 |
| 2021-05-07 | -8 |
| 2021-05-08 | -1 |
| 2021-05-09 | 5 |
| 2021-05-10 | 4 |
| 2021-05-11 | 5 |
| 2021-05-12 | 1 |
| 2021-05-13 | -1 |
| 2021-05-14 | -2 |
| 2021-05-15 | -1 |

I need to subset 2 data frames from this one. The condition is I need to loop through the rows and subset all the positive values in the same order along with 1 row before and after, that has negative values.

My expected outputs are below

Output data frame1

| date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | -2 |
| 2021-05-02 | 3 |
| 2021-05-03 | 5 |
| 2021-05-04 | 4 |
| 2021-05-05 | 6 |
| 2021-05-06 | -3 |

Output data frame2:

| date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-08 | -1 |
| 2021-05-09 | 5 |
| 2021-05-10 | 4 |
| 2021-05-11 | 5 |
| 2021-05-12 | 1 |
| 2021-05-13 | -1 |

Any suggestions on how to do this in a most efficient manner? This is a sample data, but i might have a much longer series to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter before and after values less like `0` and create list of DataFrames in list comprehension:

```
m0 = df['Value'].lt(0)
m1 = m0 & df['Value'].shift(-1).ge(0)
m2 = m0 & df['Value'].shift().ge(0)

df['g'] = m1.cumsum()
df2 = df[m1 | m2 | ~m0].copy()

dfs = [g.drop('g', axis=1) for i, g in df2.groupby('g')]
print (dfs)
[         date  Value
0  2021-05-01     -2
1  2021-05-02      3
2  2021-05-03      5
3  2021-05-04      4
4  2021-05-05      6
5  2021-05-06     -3,           date  Value
7   2021-05-08     -1
8   2021-05-09      5
9   2021-05-10      4
10  2021-05-11      5
11  2021-05-12      1
12  2021-05-13     -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean mask:

```
idx = df[(df['Value'].lt(0) & df['Value'].shift(-1).gt(0))
         | (df['Value'].lt(0) & df['Value'].shift().gt(0))].index

dfs = [df[start:end+1] for start, end in zip(idx[::2], idx[1::2])]
```

```
>>> dfs[0]
         date  Value
0  2021-05-01     -2
1  2021-05-02      3
2  2021-05-03      5
3  2021-05-04      4
4  2021-05-05      6
5  2021-05-06     -3

>>> dfs[1]
          date  Value
7   2021-05-08     -1
8   2021-05-09      5
9   2021-05-10      4
10  2021-05-11      5
11  2021-05-12      1
12  2021-05-13     -1
```

Or if you prefer create new variables:

```
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(idx[::2], idx[1::2]), 1):
    locals()[f'df{i}'] = df[start:end+1]
```

```
>>> df1
         date  Value
0  2021-05-01     -2
1  2021-05-02      3
2  2021-05-03      5
3  2021-05-04      4
4  2021-05-05      6
5  2021-05-06     -3

>>> df2
          date  Value
7   2021-05-08     -1
8   2021-05-09      5
9   2021-05-10      4
10  2021-05-11      5
11  2021-05-12      1
12  2021-05-13     -1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a great solution. It works

Answer (score -1):

---

you can try mask of neg values diff and cumum for grouping

```
mask = df['Value'].ge(0).cumsum().diff().replace(0, np.nan).ffill(limit=1).isnull().cumsum()
[grp for ind, grp in df.groupby(mask) if len(grp)>1]
```

Out:

```
              date  Value
0  2021-05-01     -2
1  2021-05-02      3
2  2021-05-03      5
3  2021-05-04      4
4  2021-05-05      6
5  2021-05-06     -3
          date  Value
7   2021-05-08     -1
8   2021-05-09      5
9   2021-05-10      4
10  2021-05-11      5
11  2021-05-12      1
12  2021-05-13     -1
```